# Touch heat map for Android homescreen

Tags: android, touchscreen, heatmap

I'm looking for an app that show me the touching distribution of my homescreens? There are [many similar apps](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-mobile-app-analytic-tools-that-offer-heat-maps-for-iOS-an-Android-Applications), but they only analyze inside particular apps, not the whole phone, or at least the homescreens.

Something like this, but for the homescreens:

[image]